# how to insert an image from base64 string

Tags: google-apps-script

The code below should insert an image blob made from the base64 string img_3k, but somehow it doesn't. What am I doing wrong?

```
var img_3k = "iVBORw0KGg..."

function searchAndReplace() {
  var body = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getBody();
  var blobImg = Utilities.newBlob(Utilities.base64Decode(img_3k), MimeType.PNG);
  body.insertImage(0, blobImg);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code was actually correct, but didn't get executed because I didn't call it from the right place. Put in the onInstall method and then it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I have no problem with your code.
I guess your problem is that you use a global variable, but you can not use global variables in Google Apps Script.

```
function searchAndReplace() {
  var img= getImage();
  var body = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getBody();
  var blobImg = Utilities.newBlob(Utilities.base64Decode(img), MimeType.PNG);
  body.insertImage(0, blobImg);
}


function getImage() {
  return "iVBORw0KGgoAAA...SUVORK5CYII=";
}
```

Comment: you can't? because I logged the value of the variable and that worked. will try your version tonight! google drive is blocked at work :(

Comment: you can use global variables, turns out my problem was that the code wasn't even executed when I tested it, I put it in the onInstall method and now it works

Answer (score 0):

just remove the "var" before your global var declaration:

```
img_3k = "iVBORw0KGg...";
```

Variables declared with var in global scope won't be visible in functions.
You could capitalize the variable as well (IMG_3K) so you know immediately that it is a static global one

Comment: you can use global variables with var, turns out my problem was that the code wasn't even executed when I tested it, I put it in the onInstall method and now it works